# What is a stateful transducer?

Tags: clojure, stateful, transducer

In the [Clojure Core documentation for the 1.7 release](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/branch-master/clojure.core-api.html) - the following functions

```
dedupe
disj!
dissoc!
filter
keep
map
random-sample
remove
replace
take-while
```

Have the following text in their API description

```
Returns a transducer when no collection is provided.
```

And the following functions

```
drop
keep-indexed
partition-all
partition-by
take
take-nth
```

Have the following text.

```
Returns a *stateful* transducer when no collection is provided.
```

In addition - there has been [this criticism of this wording](https://twitter.com/cgrand/status/509628401918156800).

[image]

My question is: **What is a *stateful* transducer?** ie what is similar about the grouped functions. (and is this the reason that [people say typing a transducer](https://twitter.com/jckarter/status/513070737997824000) would [require dependent types?](https://twitter.com/djspiewak/status/513030876662210561))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

State can be stored inside transducers.
Corresponding slides:

https://github.com/matthiasn/talk-transcripts/blob/master/Hickey_Rich/Transducers/00.34.26.jpg
https://github.com/matthiasn/talk-transcripts/blob/master/Hickey_Rich/Transducers/00.36.36.jpg

See Rich transducers talk - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mTbuzafcII